# Copy file from template to STATIC-dir

Tags: python, django, file-upload

I need copy file from:

```
<form action="test_edit_info" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {%csrf_token%}
    <input type="file" name="avatar">
    <input type="submit" value="Register"/>
</form>
```

to my **static**-dir
(just copy file from form in template into STATIC)

in **view**:

```
def test_edit_info(request):
if request.method == "POST" :
    new_ava = request.FILES['avatar']
    print "new ava: ",new_ava #return file-name
c = {}
c.update(csrf(request))
return render(request, "test_edit_personal_information.html")
```

Just copy file from template to static dir. Without any forms and models. Help, pls. Thx.

Answer (score 0):

First thing, `static` dir's like it's name say: STATIC. It contain only static files like custom js, static images, css ...

If you want to upload files you should use the `media` dir.

The view:
Don't forget to import settings

```
from django.conf import settings

if request.method == 'POST':
    if 'avatar' in request.FILES:
        file = request.FILES['avatar']

        # Other data on the request.FILES dictionary:
        #   filesize = len(file['content'])
        #   filetype = file['content-type']

        filename = file['filename']

        fd = open('%s/%s' % (settings.MEDIA_ROOT, filename), 'wb')
        fd.write(file['content'])
        fd.close()

        #return ...
```

Answer (score 0):

thx, but have error:
'InMemoryUploadedFile' object has no attribute '**getitem**'
filename = file['filename']

So, what about this?

```
from django.core.files.storage import default_storage
from django.core.files.base import ContentFile
def test_edit_info(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if 'avatar' in request.FILES:
            file = request.FILES['avatar']
            default_storage.save("E:/reg_extend_2/static/img/avatars/%s"%(file), ContentFile(file.read()))
    c = {}
    return render(request, "test_edit_personal_information.html")
```

Comment: But maybe you have criticism? Thank you.

Comment: If this work, it's perfect. Just make your path more generic, use MEDIA_ROOT for this and do not upload files to static folder.